# When trying to download a file to a specific location, I get an error

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a program in Visual Basic that can download files to a directory but unfortunately I keep on getting an error similar to this every time:

*'An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
Additional information: The given file path ends with a directory separator character.'*

It also highlights this whenever it gives me the error:

```
    My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(
     "https://copy.com/TUr3BCzMbTf4kWNk/symsrv.yes?download=1",
      appdata & "\DownloadedFiles\")
```

I've tried many google searches but nothing, this code used to work on a previous program  I've made with VB.net that downloads a game file and replaces it with the current so that users can access parts of the game they couldn't access before without doing certain tasks. Here is the code that did this:

```
    My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(
   "https://copy.com/4WkvAdu4O7sRb3gd/fn4?download=1",
   appdata & "/MMFApplications/fn4")
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong that prevents me from making my current project work?

Comment: I would say that the error message clearly explains what is wrong with your code.

Comment: Is `appdata & "\DownloadedFiles\"` a valid file name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is self-explanatory:

> The given file path ends with a directory separator character

You should write a filepath as destination (a file that ends with a file extension), not a directory path neither a filepath that ends with a **"\"** char.

The `My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile` function just downloads the data, it does not know the filename.

An example:

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(
  "https://copy.com/TUr3BCzMbTf4kWNk/symsrv.yes?download=1",
   System.IO.Path.Combine(appdata, "\DownloadedFiles\File.ext"))
```